# Use LibreOffice / OpenOffice to convert docx to pdf

Tags: python, command-line, libreoffice, openoffice.org

i want to use LibreOffice / OpenOffice commande line to convert docx file to pdf file, but i'm struggling to use these tool,  Is there anyone who knows how to use LibreOffice / OpenOffice commande line ?.

Please, If there's any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work.

```
soffice --convert-to pdf some.docx --headless
```

(I've only tried it with `.odt` files myself, but fingers crossed.)

Comment: well it didn't work, when i launch this command, the libreoffice application pop up showing the file that i want to convert and I don't get the converted pdf file.

Comment: Hmmm. `--headless` is supposed to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks. That command works for me with version `7.1.7.2-2.fc34`.