# How to convert docx file to PDF?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf, phpword

I am using Laravel 5, and I want to convert a Docx file to PDF. Can any one can suggest me best way that I could convert docs to PDF?

I tried with DOMPDF but it gave result in black & white, with all color and
images removed.

Currently I am using these package in my project.

1. phpoffice/phpword
2. barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: There are solutions but you will not satisfy with them, I am working on a project and the's core requirement is to create pdf with the doc file, I tried every solutions in php but in last i used API (convertapi.com) they have free plans but it's upto you

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/396825/convert-docx-to-pdf --  You can install something like `unoconv` then have PHP execute something like this: `doc2pdf yourfile.docx`

Comment: DOMPDF converts a DOM object to a PDF. In short it converts HTML to PDF. You have a Doc file so you would first need to convert it to HTML if you want to use DOMPDF. However there are many command line tools to do a direct conversion. What @RyanNerd suggested is one possibility. Also if you're using OpenOffice that has its own way  as well (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709687/use-libreoffice-openoffice-to-convert-docx-to-pdf)

Comment: I found and solution. We can you any online converter APIs like https://pspdfkit.com/ (have Free 100 Convertion / Month). https://cloudmersive.com/ (Paid only)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use unoconv :

https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv

It will use OpenOffice and use it's built in pdf printer.

So far it's the best results we could have;

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a direct API to `unoconv`? It looks like PHP needs to launch a shell process to do the conversion which is less than ideal in many situations.